# How to list column elements separated by comma

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table which contains the locations, the actors and activities complete by actors.
Please see the example on the below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEKV9.png)

For each location (first column) and each activity, list all the actors who are working in on that activity separated by coma.
I would like to  to have an output like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9qjd.png)

I was doing that in SQL Server, but I am now migrating to PostgreSQL.

Thanks for the advice.
I used STRING_AGG() function, but need more guidance to eliminate the duplication and loop for all value. Below is my query

```
SELECT
L.location_name,
STRING_AGG (
L.actor || ' ',
    ','
   ORDER BY
   L.actor
) activity_1
FROM
 location_actor_activity L
 WHERE activity = 'Activity_A'
```

GROUP BY
L.location_name;

Which is giving result with duplication of actors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZQNC.png)

Thank you

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D++%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` and `STRING_AGG()`.